# Python increasing the size of elements in a list by n number using interpolation

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matplotlib, interpolation

I have a list of few numbers. I want to increase the size of the list by n more numbers using the interpolation. 
My existing code and output:

```
R_data = [10, 40, 40, 40, 15]
R_op = [random.choice(R_data) for i in range(100)]
plt.plot(R_op,'-s')
plt.show()
```

Existing data:

[image]

Existing output:

[image]

Expected output: 
[image]

Comment: I don't see a question here. I don't know if it `satisfies the existing relation`, but you are indeed choosing numbers from the original list.

Comment: @Sam Sorry for the mistake. I rewrote my question. I just wanted interpolated data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want a linear relationship, and to interpolate new values between the existing values. I'd write a function to generate some number N values on the line between two existing values, and then compose your new list using that and all the intervals in your original `R_data`. Something like this should do the trick:

```
def interpolate_pts(start, end, num_pts):
    """ Returns a list of num_pts float values evenly spaced on the line between start and end """
    interval = (float(end)-float(start)) / float(num_pts + 1)
    new_pts = [0] * num_pts
    for index in range(num_pts):
        new_pts[index] = float(start) + (index+1)*interval
    return new_pts

R_data = [10.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0, 15.0]
num_pts_to_add_between_data = 4
new_data = []
for index in range(len(R_data)-1):
    first_num = R_data[index]
    second_num = R_data[index+1]
    new_data.append(first_num)  # Put the 1st value in the output list
    new_pts = interpolate_pts(first_num, second_num, num_pts_to_add_between_data)
    new_data.extend(new_pts)
new_data.append(R_data[-1]). # Add the final value to the output list

>>> print(new_data)
[10.0, 16.0, 22.0, 28.0, 34.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0, 35.0, 30.0, 25.0, 20.0, 15.0]
```

Hope that helps, happy coding!